# PSET2 Caesar: Ordered Comparison Between Pointer and Integer Error

Tags: c, compiler-errors, cs50, caesar-cipher

I am currently taking Harvard's CS50 course (Intro to CompSci).
I have not even learned pointers yet, I am confused on this error message. The line it is facing an error on in question is this: For context, the full message is as follows:

> caesar.c:48:36: error: ordered comparison between pointer and integer ('string' (aka 'char *') and 'char') [-Werror] if (plaintext[j] + key > z)

So, I am unable to understand the error message due to not yet being educated on pointers. Help50 is useless when I compiled with it. Here is my code if it is needed, I hope the comments help!

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    //Creates string key
    string key = argv[1];
    //Checks for appropriate argument count
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
        return 1;
    }
    //Checks if all argument characters are digits
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(key); i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(key[i]) == 0)
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key");
            return 1;
        }
    }

    //Gets plaintext from user
    string ciphertext = NULL;
    char z;
    string plaintext = get_string("plaintext:  ");

    //Converts plaintext to ciphertext
    for (int j = 0; j < strlen(plaintext); j++)
    {
        //Asks if character is alphabetical
        if (isalpha(plaintext[j]))
        {
            //Asks if character is uppercase and assigning ASCII code accordingly
            if (isupper(plaintext[j]))
            {
                z = 90;
            }
            else
            {
                z = 122;
            }

            //Performs conversion operation
            if (plaintext[j] + key > z)
            {
                ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j] + key - 25;
            }
            else
            {
                ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j] + key;
            }
        }
        //Keeps text the same since it is not a letter, and therefore shouldn't be shifted
        else
        {
            ciphertext[j] = plaintext[j];
        }
    }

    printf("ciphertext: %s\n", ciphertext);
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: If you must use the local variable `z`, then the assignments should be `z = 'Z';` and `z = 'z';` for clarity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//Creates string key
string key = argv[1];
```

`key` is a "string", not an integer value.

```
if (plaintext[j] + key > z)
```

The code is attempting to add a `char` to a `string`, then compare that to a `char`.

You need to go back to the basics and review the lesson until you understand arrays of characters and strings.

```
string ciphertext = NULL;
```

Here, you initialise a `string`, then seem to expect it to *somehow* grow as you later write characters into that `string`.

Sit down with a paper and pencil and diagram out what you expect to be happening with memory storage...

Comment: Thank you so much, for some reason I never caught this foolish mistake. I now have discarded of the key variable and instead cast argv[1] as an int using atoi as needed. Thank you very much, have a good day.

Comment: @tcwub You're welcome, and thank you for the 'tick'... This CS50 problem appears in many Stack Overflow questions (and answers)... Before going much further with your approach, please find and read some of those questions. The "key" is to be 26 alphabetic characters used to encipher plaintext, not an integer... You're on the wrong path, and need to get on the right one before too long... Best wishes...